# Can we feed seq2seq with word2vec?

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I have prepared dataset for training seq2seq.(one file contains questions and another has answers).
Let's say I have 1000 questions(each questions are composed of 15 words). After applying word2vec(word length 30), the shape of questions would be  (1000,15,30). 
I tried to train the network after applying

```
 question_list.reshape((1000,15,30,1))
```

And applied

```
model.fit(questions, answers, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=32)
```

Then I got an error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_4 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 15, 30, 1)
```

This means, each word should be represented as a scholar(not as 30 dimensional vector)? If so, there's no point for applying word embedding using word2vec.....

Comment: The tags for your question should be sufficient, there's no need to tag the title, that's just clutter.

Comment: Please give the line where you specified the input_shape